# How to switch src and onclick with previous and next buttons? JavaScript

Tags: javascript, image, button, onclick, src

I'm trying to make Previous and Next buttons cycle through src's and onclick's with already-visible images and of course, change others.
I'm doing this in JavaScript/HTML/CSS only, I don't know JQuery..

HTML fields:

```
<img id="prev"  onclick="prev1()"   src="Template.gif"         width="64"  height="64">
<img id="center" onclick="center1()" src="middlePictureOne.gif" width="128" height="128">
<img id="next"  onclick="next1()"   src="next.gif"             width="64"  height="64">
```

Previous Button script:

```
function prev1() {
document.getElementById("center").src="middlePictureOne.gif";
document.getElementById("center").onclick="center1()";
document.getElementById("next").onclick="next1()";
document.getElementById("prev").src="Template.gif";
}
```

Next Button:

```
function next1() {
if (condition == "true") {
document.getElementById("center").src="middlePictureTwo.gif";
document.getElementById("center").onclick="center2()";
document.getElementById("next").onclick="next2()";
document.getElementById("prev").onclick="prev1()";
document.getElementById("prev").src="previous.gif";
}else{
alert("Nope.");
}}
```

Condition: works, Next: works, Previous: having all the problems.
I've tried everything I know how to do to fix it.. just hoping the answer isn't so obvious..

Condition and how it's come to be:

```
var condition = new Boolean(0);

function center1() {
if (m1hp>0) {
    m1hp -= (heroDamage - m1def);
} else {
    onFinish();
}   
document.getElementById("hpc").innerHTML=m1hp;
}


function onFinish() {
    m1hp = 50;
    condition = "true";
}
```

Lots of irrelevant info there, but I didn't want to leave anything out in case it matters..

http://jsfiddle.net/SusuReedJango/P7KNh/

THere's the fiddle completely unedited of everything I have written.. I'm stumped and cutting out the unused parts, it wouldn't work. Probably need to replace the images if you're that motivated to solve my problem.

Comment: What is that condition variable and how you get that value?

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle?

It would be easier to debug that way.

Comment: I'm trying to, for the convenience but I can't even get some of the working parts to work on there.. :l